# Load div "data" on load

Tags: carousel, onload, episerver

I'm building an image carousel for for EPiServer, it works, but not exactly how I want it to. The current carousel starts spinning after I click the "next" button, before that it only shows one picture. I want it to start spinning directly when the page's loaded. See code for example. Ideas?

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="@(Model.Interval.GetValueOrDefault(7) * 1000)" @Html.EditAttributes(m => m.ContentArea)>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    @for (var index = 0; index < Model.Slides.Count(); index++)
    {
        var slide = Model.Slides.ElementAt(index);
        <div class="item @(index == 0 ? "active" : string.Empty) animated fadeInRight">
            @{
        Html.RenderPartial(slide.GetCarouselSlidePartialViewName(Html), slide,
            new ViewDataDictionary { { "ImageHeight", Model.ImageHeight.GetValueOrDefault(600) }, { "ImageWidth", Model.ImageWidth.GetValueOrDefault(1889) } });
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>


<button href="#carousel" data-slide="next">CLICK ME</button>
@Html.FullRefreshPropertiesMetaData(new[] { "ContentArea" })
```

So when I click on the button, it starts spinning with the href to the top div, but I want it to start as soon as the page's loaded.

Thanks/
Fredrik

Comment: You'll need to post what library and javascript you are using to activate the carousel. This isn't an EPiServer task by the way, it's a javascript task.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric's Comment to your question, is this a javascript task to start your image carosel.

All EPiserver does is to render your image-carosel with data. the rest is up to your javascript carosel library to handle the interaction/animation.

There are mostly a property on image-carosel libraries that handles if the carosel should start on load or wait for interaction.

All I can help you with, having only the attached code is to tell the javascript to click your button on load. It's not a recomended way to do it, but it solves your problem.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[href=#carousel]').click();
  });
```